# Best practice to save bus routes in a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a project that consist of a system that helps to manage a bus transportations company.

I have to store in my database the daily routes of all bus.

How do I do that? And what can I use to help user to design routes?

I'm wondering use Google Maps or something like that, to help users "design" all routes.

I can't figure ir out :S

Best reguards.

Comment: I'm assuming that when you say "trajectories", you really mean "route", right? What sort of form do the trajectories take? are they Lat/Long points? Street addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Have a "StopLocation" table, indicating every possible location any bus can stop at.

Have a "BusSchedule" table, which would be the schedule of a single bus for a day.

Then have a "BusStop" table.

This would have a foreign key reference to the "BusSchedule", a foreign key reference to "StopLocation", and the time it is due to stop there.

Comment: If the goal is not a geographically accurate description of the route this would be great. +1

Answer (score 0):

Like Josh suggested: If you're talking about a route, I'd store a list of lat/long waypoints to describe a route.

Some Links:

[Google Maps .NET Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/LatLaysFlat-Part1.aspx)

[Part 2 Advanced Usage](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/LatLaysFlat-Part2.aspx)

[Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/useritems/LatLaysFlat-Part3.asp)

(Found at [this spot](http://jmayo.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!5F243997972597CE!208.entry))

Comment: With route I mean something like in Google Maps that we can design all path from one point X to another point Y. 

Am I clear? Sorry about my poor english :S

Comment: Yes, you're clear.  That is exactly how you'd store a route to use with google maps; A list of latitude/longitude pairs (called waypoints) describing specific stops or changes in direction along the route.

Comment: How can I have access to that waypoints using ASP.NET and GoogleMaps?

Comment: Updated answer with some links